# Bootstrap-datepicker (eyecon.ro) => Option to limit year range

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Just wondering if anyone had figured out a way to set an option to limit the year range for **http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/** Bootstrap Datepicker plugin?

I want to limit the users ability to only select the current year, and really one a couple years into the future.

Comment: Was my solution acceptable?  It seems simple enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there are startDate and endDate options for this plugin.  At least, I am using them in an application I manage with eyecon.ro's datepicker extension.

So you could do something like:

```
$("#selecter").datepicker({

    startDate: '2012-11-02',
    endDate: '2014-12-31'
});
```

Additionally, I have code to do things like disable weekends - but that is a little more complex than a simple option set.

Comment: Old topic but I was looking for a way to disable weekends in this plugin; do you still have that code ?

Comment: Hi, this datepicker code was actually forked and improved with better options - I'd recommend using this one instead - https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker